# jruby -S bundle install jruby: No such file or directory -- bundle (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, path, jruby

I have my ruby on rails application and I have installed `jruby-1.7.4` in my Windows XP.

When I try to run `jruby -S bundle install` it gives me an **error**

> jruby: No such file or directory -- bundle (LoadError)

I am really stack with this error..
Please help..

Comment: Have you installed Bundler?

Comment: @Andrew how to check if the bundler is installed?

Comment: Thank I run it already and install the bundler imediately `jruby -S gem install bundler`... You can post it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bundler is probably not installed. You can check the output of `jruby -S gem list` to verify, and then install it with:

```
jruby -S gem install bundler
```

In general, a `LoadError` means you’re missing a gem dependency.